# GWT FileUpload Servlet Couldn't Retrieve File Contents

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload

I have tried to developed a web app that can upload and process local files to the GAE server. I tried to accomplish this by using FileUpload widget, but it seems that the file couldn't bee successfully uploaded by http request.

The client side code looks like this

```
private void loadLocalDataDialog()
{
    final DialogBox loadBox = new DialogBox();
    loadBox.setText("Upload Local Files");

    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setWidth("275px");
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "FileUploadServlet");

    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.setHorizontalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    form.setWidget(vp);

    final FileUpload uploader = new FileUpload();
    uploader.setName("uploadlocalfile");
    vp.add(uploader);

    loadBox.add(vp);
    loadBox.center();

    HorizontalPanel buttonPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

    buttonPanel.add(new Button("Cancel", new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadBox.hide();
        }
    }));

    buttonPanel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            form.submit();
        }
    }));

    vp.add(buttonPanel);

    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String fileName = uploader.getFilename();

            if(fileName.length() == 0)
            {
                Window.alert("Error: no file is selected. Please select a file to be uploaded.");
                event.cancel();
            }
            else if(!fileName.endsWith("xml") && !fileName.endsWith("json") && !fileName.endsWith("csv"))
            {
                Window.alert("Error: file format not supported. Only supports XML, CSV and JSON");
                event.cancel();
            }
            else
                loadBox.hide();
        }
    });

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Window.alert(event.getResults());
        }
    });
}
```

I have done some research online, and most solutions I have found said it was because the FileUpload widget does not have a name. But as you can see I have already set the name of the widget, so I have no clue what went wrong.

And here's my server side code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{   
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        InputStream is = null;

        try
        {
            FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                FileItemStream item = iterator.next();

                if(item.getFieldName().equals("uploadlocalfile") && !item.isFormField())
                {
                    is = item.openStream();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(is == null)
                response.getWriter().write("No Data");
            else
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                reader.close();

                response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
            }
        } 
        catch (FileUploadException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else 
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, "Request contents type is not supported by the servlet.");
}
}
```

No matter what file I transferred, the iterator returns nothing and "No Data" always gets printed.

I have tried the ServletFileUpload.parseRequest approach, and that doesn't work either.

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: below is the part of my web.xml file that is related to this functionality

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>loadLocalFile</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.meng.climatevisualizeapp.server.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>loadLocalFile</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/climatevisualizeapp/FileUploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Edit: this could be resulted from the fact that the http request was parsed twice. But I couldn't figure out where the first parse occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting to the servlet?

I don't see how the web.xml is configured, since it's not posted. If you aren't getting to the servlet, then you need to make sure it's defined properly in the web.xml.

Double check the gwt.xml file to ensure the ' matches the url patern, as in /FileUploadServlet, in the web.xml file for the servlet mapping.

If that is correctly named and mapped you will get to your servlet.  Start there in the servlet with a breakpoint to ensure you are getting to that point first.  Then step through each line to see what line throws the error.  You may not have initialized an object or the servlet isn't configured properly, etc...

I always check the obvious things first.

Let us know what you find out.

Comment: Ah, I did configure the web.xml file. Sorry I didn't post it. I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just stepped through my program, and it turned out that no instances of FileItemStream were parsed from the request. As a result iterator.hasNext() returns false right away...

Comment: What is in the request when it gets to the servlet?  Use something like this: Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();  and/or getParameterValues() to find out.

Comment: I used request.getReader() to get the content of the request, and I got "WebKitFormBoundary" and nothing more...